# Angular ngStyle Variable Style

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to give my div dynamic style - I want the css to come from the controller , where the css object the controller returns isn't hard-coded but changes dynamically(I need a 'top' field which is a variable). I am using ng-style to try to achieve this :

```
-html- 
<div id="preview" ng-style="setTopPosition()">

 -controller- 
    $scope.setTopPosition = function() {
    console.log("top position: "  +  $scope.topPosition);
   var retObj =  { top : $scope.topPosition , background: "green" };
    console.log(retObj);
    return retObj
};
```

Now I know that the values I'm expecting ($scope.topPosition etc) are there(they show in console log) , and I know the controller is running it's code since the div's background turns green . However , the top position part is not working . Can't ng-style use objects with variable fields ? Also , does this need to be in a custom directive instead ?

Comment: As everyone said you need to make sure you have 'px' added to the value , however my problem actually was that $scope.topPosition was being calculated asyncronously . In such a case , you need to add $scope.$apply

Comment: Well you do need to have the `px` if you're not using jQuery....

Answer (score 4):

Remove braces from `ng-style="setTopPosition()` if you want to use it as variable.

It should be `ng-style="setTopPosition`

in controller, as example:

```
 $scope.setTopPosition= {
            top : $scope.topPosition+'px',
            background : "green",
            "width": 0 + '%',
            "height": 5 + 'px'
        };
```

on any change you just set new values to `$scope.setTopPosition= {/* ... */}`

Comment: BTW is there binding between the view and $scope.topPosition ? It is determined asyncronously in my controller , maybe the problem is there...

Comment: no matter where you put new values to `$scope.setTopPosition`. Even in async tasks. It should work

Comment: @MaximShoustin if it's async you'll need to use `$scope.$apply();`

Comment: Only if you use async for jQuery. For angular you don't need it. This is a reason why prefer to use "clear" angularjs

Comment: @Joel_Blum basically just means you're applying stuff to the scope outside of angular's knowledge and you wan't to tell angular about it.

Answer (score 4):

In case anyone else comes across this question like I did, the problem for me came after upgrading from Angular 1.2.x to Angular 1.3.x.

After upgrading, it actually failed when I manually added `'px'`:

```
<span ng-style="{top: spanTop + 'px'}">I (don't) have top!</span>
```

and it started working when I removed the `'px'`:

```
<span ng-style="{top: spanTop}">I have top!</span>
```

Answer (score 3):

Unless you are using jQuery with angular you must provide the `px` part of the value. [jQlite](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/angular.element) doesn't support advanced CSS stuff like jQuery does so you should do this.

```
top : $scope.topPosition + 'px'
```

Note: The reason I say that is because the styles are applied normally in the `ng-style` directive like this: `element.css(styles);`